# Horizontal drop down menu using css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a horizontal drop down menu with 3 levels of sub menus. I have almost created all menu items. I am trying to make it more understandable to user. I want to put small arrow mark if the any li has sub menu. Is it possible to do using css? I am unable to get any solution. Please suggest me what to do?

Here is my example code:

```
     <ul id="menu_new">
    <li><a href="#" class="HeaderLink">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="HeaderLink">Applications</a>
        <ul>                                      
            <li><a href="#">Agency</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/apps/banner/web_links/NVE_South_Agency_PRDv2.ica" >NVE South</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NVE North</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Manual Crawl</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Crawl Interval</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archive List</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Visual Analytics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
        <ul>                                      
            <li><a href="#">Manage Subject</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" >Add Subject</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Edit Subject</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Delete Subject</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Export Subject</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Manual Crawl</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Crawl Interval</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archive List</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/asovbLqd/16/)

Comment: Yes it is possible to do that using css only.

Comment: As you were told when submitting the question: **post your code in the question itself**. Wrapping a JSFiddle link in code tags is breaking the rules, so I've commented it out of your question until you fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#menu_new >li:nth-child(2){
    position:relative;
    padding-right:20px;
}
#menu_new >li:nth-child(2):before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:14px;
    right:0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:10px solid transparent;
    border-top:10px solid white;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/asovbLqd/18/)

and if you want to use it on more that one place you can create a class ie: `.arrow` with the same css above.

```
[class^=arrow]{
    position:relative;
    padding-right:20px;
}
[class^=arrow]:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    width:0;
    height:0;
}

.arrow-down:before{
    right:0;
    top:14px;
    border-left:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:10px solid transparent;
    border-top:10px solid white;
}
.arrow-right:before{
    right:4px;
    top:4px;
    border-top:6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:6px solid transparent;
    border-left:6px solid white;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/asovbLqd/20/)

Comment: How to do it for all menus and sub menus?

Comment: @Sandeep Reddy K. then please check the update and demo http://jsfiddle.net/asovbLqd/20/